# How to add a formula field that sums up all records from an object linked to another object record?

Tags: formula-field, roll-up-summary, cross-object

I have two objects: `Session` and `Seance`.
Multiple `Seance records` will typically be linked to a given `Session record`.

I'm looking into adding a formula field to `Session` that will sum the ***duration field*** of all Seance records linked to that given `Session record`.

My question is how do I go about this? I've been toying around with it, but I can seem to find the right formula. Or maybe a formula field is not the right option?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formula field is not the right approach because formula fields cannot access child records (so you can't have a formula on `Session__c` that references multiple `Seance__c` records).

If these two SObjects have a master-detail relationship, then you can create a field of type "rollup summary" to manage this.

If it's just a lookup relationship between the two, then your first port of call should be [the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary tool](https://install.salesforce.org/products/dlrs/latest) (originally by Andrew Fawcett, it has been turned over to the Salesforce Commons program).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me! I was able to find the right tutorial, get a better understanding of the whole thing and fixed what I needed!